# Discord.py can't find channel by correct channel ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, discord.py

I'm trying to add a functionality to my discord bot to send a certain message every 10 seconds (content of the message is not important right now). Here's my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    await client.loop.create_task(update_task())

async def update_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()

    chn = client.get_channel('#')
    while True:

        await chn.send('message')
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

and I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

I've seen couple of similar questions already and all of the solutions are to add

```
await client.wait_until_ready()
```

before, but this doesn't work for me and I still get the error. Does anyone have a clue on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't working because `get_channel()` requires an int type object that equals an id belonging to a channel the bot can access. For example, this would be a correct usage: 
`channel = client.get_channel(700437301263728720)`